# How do I copy a non-RAID image to a RAID 1?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I backed-up the image of a computer's single drive that was not part of a RAID. Then I installed a second new, identical, empty drive.  Configuring the RAID via the BIOS erased the old drive, but I still have the back-up image.  What is the procedure for copying that image into the RAID so the Windows 7 machine boots using my original data?

Comment: Make the RAID array from two empty drives. Once set up, recover the single drive contents into the RAID arrary.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out some of my notes to verify my recollections.

To make a RAID 1 Array as you wish, you need to proceed as follows:

1. Make a backup of your image or the data on your image onto a spare drive.  This allows you to use  your initial drive as an empty drive for your RAID array. You may need to format the drive.
2. Add your second drive and make the RAID 1 Array.

Now recover your data.

Be aware that Windows 7 no longer updates as it is so far out support.  You may need to install Windows 10 instead on the new array.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it.  When I tried to move my backup image from the spare drive onto the RAID, I got 'No bootable drive found.'  I tried using a Windows installation DVD to repair that, but that didn't seem to work.  Before I dug into it further, I read/learned that Windows 7's (Intel's) software RAID was a better option for me, allowing the drives to be moved to other machines later on.  So I used that instead.  I appreciate your posts.

Comment: That is fairly much parallels how I suggested to you. Windows 7 is so long out of support that Windows 10 is a better option so I mentioned that.

Comment: Yes, it just wouldn't work with the "hardware"/BIOS RAID for some reason.  It's a work laptop so I can't buy/install a newer Windows, even if I wanted to.  I have been coding for 45 years and have found the OS security cautions to be overblown, using sensible Internet precautions instead (no email URLs/attachments, ad blockers, avoid funny websites, backups, trusted software, hardware firewalls, etc.).